# NavigationController becomes nil

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigationController embedded in my root and child views and in one of my child view I have:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    var tabs = [ItemViewController]()
    let tab = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("itemViewController") as ItemViewController
    tabs += [tab]
    self.showViewController(tabBarController, sender: self)
}
```

After I press the button, the view changes but my navigationController becomes nil. What am I doing wrong? :o

Comment: Is `ItemViewController` the navigation controller?

Comment: no, its just a child view

Comment: the weird thing is, the new view appears to have a navigation bar but my custom leftbarbutton isn't showing. On top of that, if I add more tabBarItems, in all the views except the first one, the navigation bar will overlap with my tableview

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the navigation controller into the tab bar controller--not the navigation controller's root view.

Comment: sorry, do you have some kind of example for me so I can understand it easier?

Comment: Really?  Just give the navigation controller an identifier, and use that instead of the view controller you're using now.

Comment: Doing that shows up the wrong view. My storyboard looks like this: UINavigationController -> MainView -> ItemViewController